# Detecting hold on a object - iPhone Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitouch

How can I detect if a user holds their finger down on an onscreen object for 1 second ?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: IF touch down Event

Start timer for 1 second.

IF the one second is up, check if a touch up has occurred.

There's lots of ways to do it, I'd be interested to see a guru answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least one state variable and a timer.

On a touch down inside inside the target area, set the state variable with the current time and start a 1 second timer.  On any touch move outside the target area or touch up event, clear the state variable.  After the 1 second timer has gone off, check the state variable.  If it still has a time from 1 second ago or more (and thus hasn't been cleared or changed), then the touch has been on target for at least 1 second.

Comment: Thanks Hotpaw - would you be able to post some sample code or point me to some on the web ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the timestamp property of UITouch Class

> timestamp The time when the touch
>   occurred or when it was last mutated.
>   (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly)
>   NSTimeInterval timestamp Discussion
>   The value of this property is the
>   time, in seconds, since system startup
>   the touch either originated or was
>   last changed. You can store and
>   compare the initial value of this
>   attribute to subsequent timestamp
>   values of the UITouch instance to
>   determine the duration of the touch
>   and, if it is being swiped, the speed
>   of movement. For a definition of the
>   time-since-boot value, see the
>   description of the systemUptime method
>   of the NSProcessInfo class.

You should use it with

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

in UIResponder or UIGestureRecognizer classes according to your target OS